# Why postgres drops the logical replication slot own its own after running sometime?

Tags: java, postgresql, debezium, cdc, debezium-engine

Here I am trying to running the embedded Debezium engine using springboot which connect to postgress database. When the service run it able to connect to the database and also create the replication slot, but after running for sometime, the replication slot drops on its own in postgres database which lead to broken connection with debezium.

Can anyone let me know the reason, why replication slot drops from postgres on its own?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't drop replication slots on its own.

Comment: Is it actually dropped or does it just become invalid?

Comment: It's dropping on its own. Here actually we have a 2 instance of database and when we start the application then the slot is created by one of the instance and start working. But after running some time like a day or so when I check again the slot is not present in the database. Is it because of some memory issue

Comment: Are your `slot.drop.on.stop` set to `false`?
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.8/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-property-slot-drop-on-stop